# How does this ruby statement breaks down into for manual assignment?

Tags: ruby, heroku

I have the following statement -

```
Mail.defaults do
  pop3 'mail.server.com', 110 do
    user 'user'
    pass 'pass'
  end
end
```

How can the default variables be assigned manually?

I have the above running fine on localhost - but it breaks and give a NoMethodError pop3 when I push it up to Heroku.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New version of the mail gem caused this to break, problem solved. Thanks for checking in.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the [mail gem](http://github.com/mikel/mail) by Mikel Lindsaar?
Did you [install it](http://docs.heroku.com/gems) in your Heroku app?

Comment: Yes I am. Figured out that it was due to different versions of the gem - Mikel had a few updates in the past few weeks and the .gems manifest pulled the latest.